# Is this "his" objective or just possessive?

Tags: grammar

> No poet, no artist of any art, has his complete meaning alone. **His significance, his appreciation** is the appreciation of his relation to the dead poets and artists.
>
> -- *[The Sacred Wood](http://www.english.illinois.edu/maps/poets/a_f/eliot/tradition.htm)* by T.S. Eliot

Does this mean, *his significance* and *to understand him mean to understand where he stands among the dead poets and artists*?

Answer (score 1):

> No poet, no artist of any art, has his complete meaning alone. His significance, his appreciation is the appreciation of his relation to the dead poets and artists. You cannot value him alone; you must set him, for contrast and comparison, among the dead.

While the [passage](http://www.english.illinois.edu/maps/poets/a_f/eliot/tradition.htm) (shown with its following sentence, above) does suggest a need to understand where the artist stands among earlier poets and artists, it says slightly more than that.   It asserts that comparison to those gone before is a structural requirement for criticism; ie, that such comparisons are not merely helpful for understanding, but are a requirement for meaningful comment.

That aside, *his* appears to function possessively in its several instances.